# Webbrowser control cannot display page

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control

Unless I am missing a step, I have done the following:

1. Drag webbrowser control onto form (WebBrowser1)
2. Drag button onto form
3. For button click action I did

   WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.google.com")

and I get "cannot display the page"

It does this with whatever URL I use, whether I put http first or not.

Any idea what could be causing this? Could it be some type of security restriction on my machine or network that prevents non-browsers from accessing the internet?

Comment: That should be `https`...

Comment: I followed your three steps exactly, and the WebBrowser displayed the main Google page with no errors (even without changing "http" to "https". So I'm unable to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @Blackwood it was just an assumption as if you do not supply it, it will redirect to include the secure link... I was thinking he was caught in-between that... Good ole re-write rule :)

Comment: @Codexer I agree it was worth a try. My main point is that there must be something different about the OP's situation that we haven't been told about.

Comment: @Blackwood yes I would agree...

Answer (score 0):

It's a security setting on my machine preventing it. Thanks all.

Comment: Add this to your question, this isn't an answer. Also mention what setting it was; it may be helpful if someone else come's along with the same issue.